# International law: sanctions

Tags: international, sanctions

I am analyzing the United Nations Charters, specifically focusing on sanctions. I analyzed Art. 41 (Chapter VII) that states:

> The Security Council may decide what measures not involving the use of armed force are to be employed to give effect to its decisions, and it may call upon the Members of the United Nations to apply such measures. These may include complete or partial interruption of economic relations and of rail, sea, air, postal, telegraphic, radio, and other means of communication, and the severance of diplomatic relations.

However, I was wondering if in the Charter or any other UN documents are listed (in detail) the different types of sanctions that can be imposed. I had a look at some other articles and documents, but I could not find anything.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Isn't the answer already in the provision you have quoted? "The Security Council may decide what measures" i.e. the "different types of sanctions that can be imposed" are whatever types the Security Council decides. You can't write down a list because it would be infinite.

Answer (score 2):

**I was wondering if in the Charter or any other UN documents are listed (in detail) the different types of sanctions that can be imposed**

Sanctions are specifically targeted to achieve a particular objective depending on the circumstances so it it unlikely, if not impossible, to have a definitive list.

That said, have you seen this [Fact Sheets](https://www.un.org/securitycouncil/sanctions/information) document which identifies the current sanctions regimes?

Taking a couple at random:

- The sanctions regime on Somalia comprises of:

> an arms embargo, an assets freeze, a travel ban, a charcoal ban, and an IED components ban.

- For the Democratic People’s Republic of Korea (aka North Korea) the sanctions include:

> an arms and related materiel embargo; a nuclear, ballistic missiles and other WMD programmes-related embargo; sectoral sanctions, which ban coal, minerals, fuel, food and agricultural products, earth, stone, wood, industrial machinery, transportation vehicles, seafood, textiles and luxury goods; bans, limits and places restrictions on the DPRK’s access to energy sources such as crude oil and refined petroleum products; financial sanctions; interdiction and transportation related measures; a travel ban and/or assets freeze on designated individuals and entities; a ban on providing work authorizations for DPRK nationals and a requirement to
> repatriate DPRK nationals earning income; a ban on the supply, sale or transfer of new helicopters and new and used vessels, as well as a ban on procuring statues from the DPRK; and sanctions provisions targeted at proliferation networks.

Comment: I have seen that document. However, it only focuses on specific cases, and it does not provide a list of all the sanctions that can be imposed. Anyway, thank you for your help!

Comment: @AVR we cross-posted. I added that a definitive list is unlikely due to the targeting of sanctions. I would never have thought of charcoal as being the a subject of sanctions for example